# Debugging floating-point exception in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano

I'm trying to run something that gives me a floating point exception (`Floating point exception. Core dumped`. No traceback). Since that kind of exception can't be caught using usual `try` and `except`, I can't figure out what's causing the exception.

Since I'm working on a VM, I'm not concerned about the implications of using `fpectl`. However, since I'm using anaconda python, I have no idea how to reinstall it with the appropriate flag. I tried downloading a python distribution from the official website and build it with the flag. The build seemed to be successful, but the when running `python` from the terminal, it still opens anaconda python one (I thought the default would be overwritten).

Is there a better way to debug a floating point exception, or to install `fpectl` without having to reinstall anaconda python?

Comment: What do you mean "floating point exception" does it give you an error message?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Nope. All I get is a message, `Floating point exception. Core dumped`. That's it. no traceback

Comment: You could use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to single-step through the code and find the culprit, maybe?

Comment: @SiHa I wish. I'm actually using a library called theano, which is very difficult to debug as it is. The package is very complex and there's a lot of code...

Comment: You should single step through *your* code, unless you are trying to debug the library (which, if true, would have been relevant to say up front, no?).

Comment: Are you compiling with [`DebugMode`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/debugmode.html#debugmode)? That should actually give you more details on the exception.

Comment: I've got the same issue, and I think it has to do with the decoder not being able to pick up the incoming frame rate and setting it to 0, causing a divide by 0 error. Not sure if incoming frame rate can be set somewhere?

Comment: Ubuntu specific issue with memory allocation